# Linux environment, synchronization between timer callback and application threads

Tags: linux, multithreading, timer, callback, synchronization

If I have two threads A and B in a process, and thread A creates a timer, Since the timer callback can interrupt either thread, does that mean the access to shared object(among either thread and timer callback) needs to be synchronized?
it is also said that the synchronization between timer callback and application thread is not secure, say, thread A locked a mutex mA, then it is interrupted by timer callback, in the timer callback it also tries to lock mA, now deadlock happens.
Am I right in the above statement? if it is true, there is many limitation in the timer callback to avoid synchronization problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution to signals related problems, such as those you bring, is to not handled signals asynchronously. There are several ways to do that.

First, if a signal arrives at a process group, it is good practice to only have one thread that does not block the signal.

Next, precise solution depends on how your program's main loop looks like. Most likely, this is a loop around `select`/`epoll`. If so, look up `pselect` and `epoll_pwait`, and make sure you understand what they say. Handling your signals in this way mean that your signal handler runs synchronized with your actual program, removing almost all restrictions from it.

An even better solution (but one that is Linux only) is to not handle the signal with a signal handler, but to turn it into a file descriptor using `signalfd`.

Last, but by no means least, if all you want is to handle file descriptors + timer based actions, there are libraries that wrap that for you in a performance oriented implementation. You also gain platform independence at no extra charge.

Two such libraries are `libevent` and `libev`.

Comment: Thank for the informative suggestions!
We finally used a busy-checking mechanism:
  the main loop uses a message-queue to receive incoming message,  each loop first check the message queue with IPC_NOWAIT and handle it if any, then, it checks the timer list to see if any timer reaches and invokes it.
uses pselect is really a perfect solution, but our situation is that the library needs to be used in vxworks.
do you know if there is similiar solution in vxworks - to provide a good timer solution that callback be run in a synchronized manner?

Comment: You labeled your question `linux`, so I gave you a Linux answer. `pselect` is a Posix standard function, but vxWorks isn't exactly Posix compatible, so I don't know what's your solution there. I suggest asking again and labeling it vxWorks.